# Image glitches on page load in Shopify

Tags: html, shopify

Wondering if this image glitches caused by lazyload? It's not happening so often tho. Anybody experienced this before? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try PNG, I also experience issue when I edit and export JPG from photshoop

Comment: It's actually png. :)